# Akima function 'bilinear' is only returning zeros when making interpolations in RStudio

Tags: r, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate data from ERA5 Interim to a finer resolution (from 0.1° to 0.05°). I'm using the bilinear function from the akima package in Rstudio to do so, but whenever I try to compute it I only get zeros. What might be the reason behind this?

As a simplification of my data, I run this line

```
test_bilinear = bilinear(c(-70.6, -70.5, -70.4, -70.3, -70.2), 
                         c(-34.0, -34.1, -34.2, -34.3, -34.4), 
                         matrix(c(151, 151, 154, 162, 171, 142, 142, 146, 155, 167, 137, 135.09, 141.57, 153.08, 164.60, 139.00, 139.22, 144.59, 154.31, 163.37, 143.13, 144.59, 149.90, 158.23, 164.99), nrow = 5, ncol = 5),
                         c(-70.6, -70.35, -70.65, -71.85), 
                         c(-34.0, -34.05, -34.37, -33.88))[["z"]]

> test_bilinear
[1] 0 0 0 0
```

But, when I use an example of the bilinear function, it works as intended.

```
x <- c(0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10)
y <- c(50, 55, 60, 65, 70)
z <- matrix(rnorm(25), 5, 5)
x0 <- seq(0, 10, .5)
y0 <- seq(50, 70, length = length(x0))

bilinear(x, y, z, x0, y0)[["z"]]

> bilinear(x, y, z, x0, y0)[["z"]]
 [1] 0.5212130 0.4629981 0.6316416 1.0271434 1.6495036 2.4987221 1.6069258 0.9774763 0.6103738
[10] 0.5056182 0.6632096 0.6206286 0.6874867 0.8637841 1.1495206 1.5446963 0.7932024 0.3964096
[19] 0.3543180 0.6669276 1.3342383
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: I see two things that might cause problems:  1.  Your y values are in decreasing order.  2.  Some of your (x0, y0) points are outside the range of x and y.  The documentation for `akima::bilinear` is really poor, so I don't know if either of these things is supposed to be different, but I'd be suspicious of both of them.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation doesn't say this, but apparently `akima::bilinear` assumes that both `x` and `y` are increasing, and that `x0` and `y0` fall in their range.

In your data, `y` is `c(-34.0, -34.1, -34.2, -34.3, -34.4)` which is decreasing.  So put it in increasing order, and modify `z` in a corresponding way.

You'll still have the problem that only the first two of your `(x0, y0)` points falls  in the range of your data.  To fix that, you'll need more data, or fewer points to interpolate.

Here are some calculations to illustrate:

```r
# Your original data:

x <- c(-70.6, -70.5, -70.4, -70.3, -70.2) 
y <- c(-34.0, -34.1, -34.2, -34.3, -34.4) 
z <- matrix(c(151, 151, 154, 162, 171, 142, 142, 146, 155, 167, 137, 135.09, 141.57, 153.08, 164.60, 139.00, 139.22, 144.59, 154.31, 163.37, 143.13, 144.59, 149.90, 158.23, 164.99), nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
x0 <- c(-70.6, -70.35, -70.65, -71.85)
y0 <- c(-34.0, -34.05, -34.37, -33.88)

library(akima)

# Completely bad results:
bilinear(x, y, z, x0, y0)
#> $x
#> [1] -70.60 -70.35 -70.65 -71.85
#> 
#> $y
#> [1] -34.00 -34.05 -34.37 -33.88
#> 
#> $z
#> [1] 0 0 0 0

# Fix y and z:
y <- rev(y)
z <- z[, 5:1]
bilinear(x, y, z, x0, y0)
#> $x
#> [1] -70.60 -70.35 -70.65 -71.85
#> 
#> $y
#> [1] -34.00 -34.05 -34.37 -33.88
#> 
#> $z
#> [1] 151.00 154.25   0.00   0.00

x0 < min(x)
#> [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1.9000)</sup>

We now have some reasonable interplated values for the 1st two points, but not the last two.  But look at `x0 < min(x)`:  it is `TRUE` for the last two points.  They are out of range.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. I was gonna post it but you were faster!

Exactly, it seems that bilinear needs everything in increasing order: x, y, x0 and y0.

About the out of bound points: those were experimental points made in order to see if bilinear was telling me "the zeros means is out of bounds" or just "the value is zero". 

Again, thank you very much!

Comment: The `akima` package has a troubling license -- it forbids commercial use.  The `interp` package replaces several of the `akima` functions, but not `bilinear`.  Maybe it would be worth your time to do an independent implementation of `bilinear`.  The description makes it sound relatively easy.

Comment: If you did this, you could fix some of this bad behaviour, and submit it to `interp`.